# intent activity won't start if map is included in the layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-navigationview

My class extends `FragmentActivity`... Intent activity will start when map is not included in the layout.
But unfortunately, the intent activity won't start if **activity_main_map** is included in **activity_main_nav**. Can somebody help me?

```
public class MainMapActivity extends FragmentActivity

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_nav);

    setUpToolbarDrawer();
    setUpNavView();
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.add_bus) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMapActivity.this, AddBusActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.add_driver) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMapActivity.this, AddDriverActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void setUpToolbarDrawer() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}

public void setUpNavView() {
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

**activity_main_nav**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<include
    layout="@layout/activity_main_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**activity_main_map**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Can somebody help me fix my problem? I badly need this to fix

Comment: Please share the stacktrace is your app crashing ?

Comment: @gaurav4sarma no, my app didn't crashed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put the appBar and the included map inside a `LinearLayout`
Just like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_main_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```